# Audio Streaming C++ Server / Client

Tags: c++, qt, networking, audio, streaming

I am actually working on a server-client multimedia player. This player can be a server to stream a MP3 file (or wma, wav, ogg, flac ...) over the network to another player (client).

I worked first on a basic network communication (client-server), that send and receive bits. But I have a problem : the audio encoding. I need a tool to encode the audio data to be able to send a little part of it through the network and let the client play it before the next part is coming.

I saw a few tools on internet such as BASS library, Live555 ... I used to work with PortAudio for student's projects but I hate it.

So basically, I need a tool to encode audio data (server side), (I can send it over lan), and decode data to play it (client-side).

Do you guys have some ideas about how to do it ? Which tool could be useful for me in that case?

PS : I am trying to use Qt library for the network interface (it is efficient, and it works on windows, linux, mac) ... Is there any audio streaming tool included in the Qt library ?

Comment: Hi there... Have you checked this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692333/how-i-can-play-streaming-audio-over-ethernet-in-qt

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link.
Since a part of the code is missing, I have some trouble to make it working to test it. However, the udp part using Qt tools seems to be good. But I don't think that the playing part is complete. It is only made to transfer and play wav file.
What kind of tool can I use to encode different media file (mp3, wav, ogg, wma, flac ...) in order to transmit it, then play it on the other side ?

Comment: Good to know it helped... I've never used QT for decoding/encoding but I've found a library [QAudioCode](https://github.com/visore/QAudioCoder)  in QT which has a really simple interface and supports .wav, .mp3 and flac... Can you check it out if it fits your requirements... Let me know if it doesn't then we'll find other options...

Comment: I checked it out, its a great tool too encode mp3, but I found another library called live55(.com), also used in VLC media player. It proposes some samples, including a streaming server and a client respecting the RTP/RTSP protocol used everywhere.

Comment: Alright... That's pretty cool... Let  me check it out too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/). It can convert almost anything to anything (so it claims) and it is a widely used open source library. 
We use it in our application mainly for decoding video/audio streams.